# Prove that rank $(g \circ f)\le \min[\operatorname{rank}(f),\operatorname{rank}(g)]$; $g$ and $f$ are linear mappings

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that rank $(g \circ f)\le \min[\operatorname{rank}(f),\operatorname{rank}(g)]$, where $g:V \to W$ and $f:U \to V$ are linear mappings and $U,V,W$ are vector spaces. I do not understand how it can be less than? Can someone explain the proof to me.

Comment: One example where it's less than: all three vector spaces are $\Bbb{R}^2$; $f$ is represented by $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)$; $g$ is represented by $\left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{array}\right)$. Then $g \circ f$ is the zero map even though both $f$ and $g$ have rank $1$.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, we can take $U = V = W = \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $f$ and $g$ be the projections onto the $x$-coordinate and $y$-coordinate, respectively.  This means, for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$ f((x,y)) = (x,0) \qquad \text{and} \qquad g((x,y)) = (0,y).$$

Each of these transformations has rank 1, but the composition has rank 0 since for any $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we have
$$(g \circ f)((x,y)) = g(f((x,y))) = g((x,0)) = (0,0).$$